# empty scheduler, refill scheduler with the URL in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

The problem is, I'm scraping a website using proxies, so the website will close some information that I needed when I request to the website after some counting. So what I'm doing is, I scrape as much as item I can **without login + proxies**, but after some scraping, I get to know that site won't allow data. So now I have to login! **(now login + proxies)** So after login I continue scraping. NOW THE PROBLEM IS, There are some URLs that are already in the queue(Scheduler) which will get scraped without a login(So i want to fetch that URL(s) with login so i can scrape that data successfully.) so **I want to empty scheduler which consist url which generated without login.**

So here the things that I have done already.

**1**. I login(successful).

**2**. Enable cache

**3** And set priority 1 to Login URl too

**possible solution regarding me.**

**1**. Reload all the queued URL which got a response before I perform login(so I have to do cache after response)!
   How can I do that??

**2** Empty the queue of Scheduler so I can refill it with Login(so caching not required).
 how to do it?? 
**How can I empty scheduler queue through the script.**

Comment: Please have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
And especially look at [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one of the next possibilities:

- Do the crawling always logged
- Get all the urls in an array and iterate it manually to control when the login is needed ([Scrapy example](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#our-first-spider))
- You can set a Boolean into a DB (using [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) or another system) to know if you need to be logged in the next crawled request
- You can set a Boolean in an [instance variable](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) in the spider to know if you need to be logged in the next crawled request